# Stored procedure efficiency on views or tables

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures

What's faster?

- Running a stored proc on many views made to hide the complexity of the underlying DB tables
- Running a more complicated stored proc directly against the DB tables

**EDIT**

The above is assuming that both stored proc and views are well developed, the most efficient and readable possible

Thank you

Comment: That entirely depends on the specific implementation of the views and/or stored procedures.  One approach is not intrinsically faster than the other.  Views allow abstraction and/or encapsulation, but build them wrong or use them wrong and then performance can suffer.  A larger more complex stored procedure allows greater degree of control, but with less encapsulation / reuse of code, making it harder to write/test/debug/maintain.  In short, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Views do not have execution plan. The plan is created when they are used and is stored in execution plan of stored procedure in this case. As long as You end up with the same query, there is no difference if You use views or not.

Hiding complexity in views is great for maintenance because of DRY principle and I recommend that. Just make sure You do it right and engine can eliminate parts of views you do not use especially when composing them.